# Cloudfront + Woocommerce - cart not updating

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce, amazon-cloudfront

I have recently added cloudfront to my wordpress site hosted on AWS.

At first my cart would not register any products being added to it - so I made a behaviour in cloudfront to not cache the cart, my account and checkout pages.

Now my users can only add a single product at a time - after adding a second it overwrites what was added in intially.

I believe it must be a problem with the caching behaviour of cloudfront. can anyone help me with what settings I need to get woocommerce to play nice with cloudfront?

here are my settings:

[image: settings]

Answer (score 5):

This is what I used to fix the issue. I set up Cloudfront using the AWS wordpress plugin. It created a distribution for me with 5 different "behaviours". These behaviours are found by logging into the AWS CloudFront console and navigating to the "behavious' tab in your distribution settings.

**Here are step by step instructions.**
Go to Cloudfront. Find your distribution. Click on the ID or click the checkbox and open the settings. Find the 'behaviors' tab and open in. You should have a "default(`*`)" behavior in there. Open and edit that behavior. Add "wp_woocommerce_session_*" to the 'Whitelist Cookies' box and the click, "Yes, Edit" to update at the bottom of the page. Changes should take effect immediately.

You will also likely want to whitelist these cookies as well:

```
woocommerce_items_in_cart*
woocommerce_cart_hash*
woocommerce_recently_viewed*
wp-resetpass* (for WP password resets)
```

You can read more about [Woocommerce cookies here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-cookies/):

[image: help photo one]

[image: help photo two]

Comment: This saved me a lot of hassle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i ended up solving this by whitelisting all cookies in cloudfront.

I tried to only whitelist the woocommerce cookies but this didnt work - so not sure which ones I am missing, will keep exploring over the next few days

in the meantime can anyone ansewr if there is a security risk is whitelisting all coookies in cloudfront?

Comment: The risk is not security, it is performance.  The more cookies you forward, statistically, the lower the cache hit rate, but the most significant impact is the impact of forwarding any cookies at all, so that is not really a concern, here.  The problem here is that unless you have identified which specific cookie is the issue, forwarding extra cookies may only have solved the problem coincidentally during your testing and it may not be *fully* solved.

Comment: I'm sorry I understand part of your comment but not the last part - are you saying that the problem may not be because of cookie forwarding but it solved it by accident?

Comment: Correct.  It sounds like it fixed it, but you need to understand how your application works, in order to verify that.  You should not have to forward all the cookies, but perhaps only one or more additional cookies.  Examine the response headers from the site, looking for `Set-Cookie` to see what the site is asking the browser to add.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie I whitelisted is `wp_woocommerce_session_*`. This resolved the same issue I had.